# After setting the style of a Data Role (if the position of it is next to somthing else) it doesn't work- when clicking on it

Tags: javascript

After setting the style of a Data Role (if the position of it is next to somthing else) it doesn't work- when clicking on it.
My code:
btn

it didn't go to the URL that I sent it to.

Then I tried this:

```
<a data-role="button" href="#popupRecordFilter" data-rel="modalview" class="selected_btn">btn</a>
 .selected_btn
    {

    position:absolute; top:62px; width:10px;

    }
```

and it still wasn't successfull

Comment: you want Apply style when click on button??

Comment: i want to add style for the button in general- not just after clicking on it!

Comment: but if i add style to the button- the clicking function doesn't work